# MVC5 and System.Security.Principal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a very simple view that basically show's how the application sees the user (so that I can resolve a different issue).

To do that I am using Systmes.Security.Prinicipal (as coded below).  And in Dev/IIS, it works perfectly.  But move the app to PRD and I get an error page.  I don't understand why it works on one platform and not the PRD server. (side note:  This is just an extra view I created in an existing live prd applicaiton, for test purposes. The rest of the live site works as designed.  Only this new view fails).  I have added the reference, as well.

Basic Controller (WhoAMI)

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;


namespace ICS20web.Controllers
{
public class WhoAmIController : Controller
{
    // GET: WhoAmI
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        string MyName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        ViewBag.FullID = MyName;
        String result = MyName.Substring(MyName.Length - 6);
        ViewBag.WhoAmI = result;


        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;
        String name = userPrincipal.DisplayName;
        ViewBag.MyRealID = name;




        return View();
    }
```

Index View

```
<table class="table">
<tr>

    <td>

        <h3>
            Full ID:  @ViewBag.FullID;
            <br>Short ID:  @ViewBag.WhoAmI;
            <br> My Name:  @ViewBag.MyRealID;
        </h3>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Again - in debug on IIS, it displays my credentials as expected.  Move to PRD server and I get a general error.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: try HttpContext.User.Identity.Name

Comment: You seem to be confusing the identify of the user who the application is executing as (`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`) with the identity of the user accessing the site (`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`).

Comment: I've edited your question, and rolled it back to what it was originally. Please don't post edit solution into the question itself. Instead, you can post a separate answer. However, in this case others have already asked the same question and gotten an answer, so I've marked yours as a duplicate of that.